# Is it possible to check in which VisualStudio edition the application was created?

Tags: visual-studio

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to check in which VisualStudio edition (whether it was Professional, Community, Enterprise, ..) and version (2010, 2015, ...) an application has been created by only looking at the given end product (executable, web page, ...)

By application I mean anything that can be done in VS - app, web site, office add-in, ...

Since MS released a fully functional [CommunityEdition](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs), I wonder if and how any Software Asset Management tool can check if a program is used legally.

Comment: That's not possible.  Programs created with the free VS editions are not marked in any special way and are never "illegal".  The EULA forbids large enterprises from using the community edition.  Nothing that VS does inside the program to say that it was created by an employee of such a large enterprise.  Only the copyright notice he embeds :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment - could you make it an answer, so I can accept it?